# How to check if stdout was closed - without writing data to it?

Tags: go

I wrote a program that reads data, filters and processes it and writes it to stdout. If stdout is piped to another process, and the piped process terminates, I get SIGPIPEd, which is great, because the program terminates, and the pipeline comes to a timely end.

Depending on the filter parameters however, there may not be a single write for tens of seconds, and during that time there won't be a SIGPIPE, although the downstream process has long finished. How can I detect this, without actually writing something to stdout? Currently, the pipeline is just hanging, until my program terminates of natural causes.

I tried writing a zero-length slice

```golang
if _, err := os.Stdout.Write([]byte{}); err != nil
```

but unfortunately that does not result in an error.

N.B. Ideally, this should work regardless of the platform, but if it works on Linux only, that's already an improvement.

Comment: a keepalive signal has many benefits.  is any write a no-op?

Comment: @DanielFarrell That would be a workaround if there really is no other way. It would amount to an interface change, forcing me to change all downstream processes.

Comment: Anticipating `SIGPIPE` amounts to predicting the future. If you're not getting an error after the downstream process is done, it sounds like that process is not terminating correctly, it's just blocking. Can you try to see if you cat get the readers in the pipeline to exit completely?

Comment: @JimB I want to know if stdout is still open or not - that is not anticipating the future, it is reading an event from the past, so don't take the question title too literal. But you seem to only get an error if you actually write to stdout, which my process may not be doing for a long time. And I have confirmed that the reader exits just fine, e.g. by using standard tools like `head -c <count>`.

Comment: To augment what @JimB said, note that if the pipe reader is still reading, and will read 1 byte and then close the pipe and you write *two* bytes, your write may fail and you may get a `SIGPIPE`, but if you write *one* byte, your write will succeed. Or, if the reader isn't reading but still has the pipe open, a test will say that things are OK, and by the time the test finishes, the reader may have closed the pipe so that a write will fail. You literally *cannot* guarantee anything about a *future* write call. You must simply call `write` and see what has now happened in the immutable past.

Comment: If you're only interested in whether there are still readers on the pipe, well, unfortunately, the only test for that is to write to it and see if the write fails. Note that if you block or ignore `SIGPIPE` at the OS level, you'll just get a failed `write` system call, but the Go runtime system is full of special case weirdness around signals including SIGPIPE; I'm not sure there's a sane way to do this reliably in all Go versions.

Comment: @DanielFarrell How would I do a heartbeat if the process at the receiving end of the pipe is a standard tool like e.g. `head`? What can I send that `head` would ignore?

Comment: to try to help you mor effectively, can you try to provide a minimal reproducible example ? I do believe you are facing an implementation issue of using pipes.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer it in Go, but you can likely find a way to use this.
If you can apply Poll(2) to the write end of your pipe, you will get an notification when it becomes un-writable.   How to integrate that into your Go code depends upon your program; hopefully it could be useful:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void sp(int sno) {
    write(2, "sigpipe!\n", 9);
    _exit(1);
}

int waitfd(int fd) {
    int n;
    struct pollfd p;
    p.fd = fd;
    p.events = POLLOUT | POLLRDBAND;
    /* RDBAND is for what looks like a bug in illumos fifovnops.c */
    p.revents = 0;
    if ((n=poll(&p, 1, -1)) == 1) {
        if (p.revents & POLLOUT) {
            return fd;
        }
        if (p.revents & (POLLERR|POLLHUP)) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "poll=%d (%d:%s), r=%#x\n",
        n, errno, strerror(errno), p.revents);
    return -1;
}

int main() {
    int count = 0;
    char c;
    signal(SIGPIPE, sp);
    while (read(0, &c, 1) > 0) {
        int w;
        while ((w=waitfd(1)) != -1 &&
            write(1, &c, 1) != 1) {
        }
        if (w == -1) {
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "wrote %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

In linux, you can run this program as: `./a.out < /dev/zero | sleep 1` and it will print something like: `wrote 61441`.  You can change it to sleep for 3s, and it will print the same thing.  That is pretty good evidence that it is has filled the pipe, and is waiting for space.
Sleep will never read from the pipe, so when its time is up, it closes the read side, which wakes up poll(2) with a POLLERR event.

If you change the poll event to not include POLLOUT, you get the simpler program:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int waitfd(int fd) {
    int n;
    struct pollfd p;
    p.fd = fd;
    p.events = POLLRDBAND;
    p.revents = 0;
    if ((n=poll(&p, 1, -1)) == 1) {
        if (p.revents & (POLLERR|POLLHUP)) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "poll=%d (%d:%s), r=%#x\n",
        n, errno, strerror(errno), p.revents);
    return -1;
}

int main() {
    if (waitfd(1) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Got an error!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

where "Got an error!" indicates the pipe was closed.   I don't know how portable this is, as poll(2) documentation is kinda sketchy.
Without the POLLRDBAND (so events is 0), this works on Linux, but wouldn't on UNIX (at least Solaris and macos).   Again, docs were useless, but having the kernel source answers many questions :)

This example, using threads, can be directly mapped to go:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int Events = POLLRDBAND;

void sp(int sno) {
    char buf[64];
    write(2, buf, snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%d: sig%s(%d)\n", getpid(), sys_siglist[sno], sno));
    _exit(1);
}

int waitfd(int fd) {
    int n;
    struct pollfd p;
    p.fd = fd;
    p.events = Events;
    /* RDBAND is for what looks like a bug in illumos fifovnops.c */
    p.revents = 0;
    if ((n=poll(&p, 1, -1)) == 1) {
        if (p.revents & (POLLERR|POLLHUP)) {
            return -1;
        }
        return fd;
    }
    return -1;
}

void *waitpipe(void *t) {
    int x = (int)(intptr_t)t; /*gcc braindead*/
    waitfd(x);
    kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int ac) {
    pthread_t killer;
    int count = 0;
    char c;
    
    Events |= (ac > 1) ? POLLOUT : 0;

    signal(SIGPIPE, sp);
    signal(SIGUSR1, sp);

    pthread_create(&killer, 0, waitpipe, (int *)1);
    while (read(0, &c, 1) > 0) {
        write(1, &c, 1);
        count++;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "wrote %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that it parks a thread on poll, and it generates a SIGUSR1.  Here is running it:

```
mcloud:pipe $ ./spthr < /dev/zero | hexdump -n80
0000000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
0000050
185965: sigUser defined signal 1(10)
mcloud:pipe $ ./spthr < /dev/zero | sleep 1
185969: sigUser defined signal 1(10)
mcloud:pipe $ ./spthr | sleep 1
185972: sigUser defined signal 1(10)
mcloud:pipe $ ./spthr < /dev/zero | hexdump -n800000
0000000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
00c3500
185976: sigBroken pipe(13)
```

In the first command, hexdump quits after 80 bytes, the poll is fundamentally racing with the read+write loop, so it could have generated either a sigpipe or sigusr1.

The second two demonstrate that sleep will cause a sigusr1 (poll returned an exception event) whether or not the write side of the pipe is full when the pipe reader exits.

The fourth, uses hexdump to read a lot of data, way more than pipe capacity, which more deterministically causes a sigpipe.

You can generate test programs which model it more exactly, but the point is that the program gets notification as soon as the pipe is closed; not having to wait until its next write.

Comment: I've checked out your second version on my Linux box, but I can't get it to work for me. My (modified) main: `int main() { fprintf(stdout, "1\n2\n"); waitfd(1); }` Running `./a.out` prints the 2 lines and blocks forever - so far, so good. `./a.out | head -1` prints nothing and blocks forever, so I tried `unbuffer ./a.out | head -1` which results in printing one line, but then also blocks forever. Isn't `waitfd` supposed to return at some point after `head -1` has called it quits? (Btw. it doesn't matter if I pipe in `/dev/zero` or not)

Comment: Yes, in the second version it does no i/o, and the wait does not wait for i/o space in the pipe (unlike the first one with POLLOUT.   I would think this second way could be used to park a goroutine until the pipe closed, then have it send on a channel to match your framework.   Sleep is a better read end of the pipe because you can readily tell that you only get the notification when the pipe is closed.

Comment: +1 I got `./a.out | head -1` to work with your first version of `waitfd()`. However, I had to `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);` to get a timely `-1` from `waitfd()`. I didn't need `signal(SIGPIPE, sp);`.

Comment: I spoke too soon. It only seemed to work because I was also printing something to stdout. When I'm not printing to stdout, `waitfd(1)` will always return `1`, even thought the process down the pipe has long died.

Comment: That is because there is space in the pipe, so the POLLOUT condition is always true; the use of /dev/zero was to fill the pipe, so the only condition would be the pipe close.

Comment: I see. But unfortunately, I'm using stdin for other purposes already, so piping in /dev/zero is not an option...

Comment: That is just for demonstrating how this works; you have to apply the mechanism to your problem.

Comment: Thanks so much for following up! I'll hope I'll find the time to look into this later this week.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real solution to the problem - namely, detecting if the process down the pipe has terminated without writing to it - but here is a **workaround**, suggested in a comment by Daniel Farrell: (Define and) use a heartbeat signal that will get ignored downstream.

As this workaround is not transparent, it may not be possible if you don't control all processes involved.

Here's an example that uses the NUL byte as heartbeat signal for text based data:

```
my-cmd | head -1 | tr -d '\000' > file
```

my-cmd would send NUL bytes in times of inactivity to get a timely EPIPE / SIGPIPE.

Note the use of `tr` to strip off the heartbeats again once it has served its purpose - otherwise they would end up in `file`.